# How to assign text following command to a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

TL;DR
How do you assign the text following the command to a variable in bash?

Ex: /path/to/script [value to assign to variable]

I am writing a script that essentially filters out information from a dig and whois in a format that I like. Right now, I have it set assign user input to the variable for the domain I want to query. I am doing this using 'read'. So it looks like:

read -p "Domain:" domain

This requires running the command and then putting in the domain, whereas I would like to put the domain after the command, similar to what you would do when doing a normal dig or whois.

Such as:
./script google.com

I imagine that its not too complicated and that its a matter of redirecting stdin(0) to a variable. Though I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Usually just a normal `key=value` pair, like `MYVARIABLE=$(read -p "Domain:" domain)` would save the result of `read -p ...` back to MYVARIABLE.

Comment: http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_read_command_line_arguments_in_a_bash_script

Comment: With how the 'read' is set up, it's already assigning my input to the variable of $domain without having to do a pair. Id like to be able to  just put the domain after the command and have it assign that value to a variable, just so its one step instead of two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read CLI arguments in bash as ordered index pretty much like AWK.

So if your script is called `better-dig.sh`, when issuing:

```
$ better-dig.sh google.com
```

In your script you must capture the argument google.com within $1, scriptname within $0.

Then:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi I'm $0 - will call dig with $1"
dig $1 | awk 'the rest of your script'
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments on command line are present as $1, $2...

Answer (score 0):

Commandline arguments are already assigned to variables 1,2,3,4...  To access them just use $1, $2. For example

```
echo "argument one is $1"
```

optionally you can assign to another variable

```
site=$1
```